# How to get file size before writing it to server?

Tags: java, file, io, inputstream

When try to convert `InputStream` into byte array to know size of the file being uploaded. I am able to get size, but `InputStream.read()` becomes -1. How to check file size before writing it to server?

My current code gives me size , but `InputStream` reaches the end.

```
    private static byte[] readFully(InputStream input) throws IOException
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int bytesRead;
    byte []bytes=null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
        System.out.println("Buffer is "+input.read(buffer));
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    bytes=output.toByteArray();
    output.close();
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get a `java.io.File` instance instead of an InputStream?

Comment: Nope. Actually i am getting inputStream and i am using this on Oracle Application Framework, where [BlobDomain](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/apirefs.1111/e10653/oracle/jbo/domain/BlobDomain.html)  class returns inputStream only.

Comment: BlobDomain has a getLength method

Comment: You're calling `input.read(buffer)` twice for each loop iteration, but only writing to `output` once.  You call `read()` in the `while` statement itself with the return value in `bytesRead`.  You call `read()` again in the `System.out.println()` statement but discard the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing a web-server in Java, please take a look at the following link:

http://www.prasannatech.net/2008/11/http-web-server-java-post-file-upload.html

You must try to read the incomming information until you found its boundary.

You can't use read() method now, because the InputStream may not be ready to be read yet.